# jQuery to calculate avg of values present inside a td of a table

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I am using googlecharts plugin in order to generate a column chart.

i also want to get an average of the values present in the td. Is it possible through google charts plugin or can anyone help me in writing ajquery to calculate the avg.
After calculating the avg I need to add it in paragraph tag with class "avg".
Thanks for the help.

My code is:

```
<table id="weather">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Mar</th>
                            <th>Apr</th>
                            <th>May</th>
                            <th>Jun</th>
                            <th>Jul</th>
                            <th>Aug</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Weather</th>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                            <td>24</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        gvChartInit();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#weather').gvChart({
        chartType: 'ColumnChart',
        gvSettings: {
            width: 100,
            height: 40,
            colors:['gray'],
            hAxis: {textPosition: 'none'},
            vAxis: {minValue: 0, textPosition: 'none', gridlines: {color: '#ffffff'}},
            legend: {position: 'none'}
        }
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: Here the avg should come as 21

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
avg = 0, amount = 0;
$('td').each(function(){
    avg += +($(this).text());
    amount++;
});
avg /= amount;
$('.avg').text(avg);
```

But you might want to make sure it's the right `td`, so you could have the `tr`'s id something like 'weather', then just change `$('td').each()` to `$('#weather td').each()`

Comment: Thank you very much its working fine after modifying it a bit:
declare variables variables separately like var avg=0; var amount=0;
Then remove 0 from the function i.e. make it as avg += +($(this).text());

Finally it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it to work! and yeah, sorry i was thinking python with the variables :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var avg=0;

$('#weather td').each({function(){
            avg=avg+parseInt($(this).text());
         });

avg=avg/$('#weather td').length;
```

or

```
var avg=0;
var count=0;
   $('#weather td').each({function(){
                avg=avg+parseInt($(this).text());
                count=count+1;
             });

    avg=avg/count;
```

after you can add avg on p tag by

```
$('p.avg').html(avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return an average for you:

```
var totalVal = 0,
    iCount = $('#weather').find('td').length;
$('#weather').find('td').each(function(i,val){
    totalVal = totalVal + parseInt($(val).text());
});
alert('Avg = '+totalVal/iCount);
```

​